# Ubuntu login issue with broken laptop screen

Tags: ubuntu, login, bios

My Samsung laptop has a broken screen, hence I'm using an external one. However, external displays only in extended mode. After <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I can start the terminal .... but .... apparently I forgot the password .... and Ubuntu doesn't allow me to use external mode in bios?

Any ideas?

p.s I tried pretty much everything on the web I reckon.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be to use a bootable medium (e.g., USB stick) to boot. The resulting live system should allow you to use the external monitor instead of the internal one. Then, you can mount your internal hard drive and do your stuff. I assume, it should even be possible to reset your password via this live environment, but if extracting data is your goal, that might not be necessary.